# Dominoes where NO two connected tiles have a number in common

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, dominoes

Take the following set of ten dominoes: 
<kbd>0 | 1</kbd>, <kbd>0 | 2</kbd>, <kbd>0 | 3</kbd>, <kbd>0 | 4</kbd>, <kbd>1 | 2</kbd>, <kbd>1 | 3</kbd>, <kbd>1  | 4</kbd>, <kbd>2 | 3</kbd>, <kbd>2 | 4</kbd>, <kbd>3 | 4</kbd>

Arrange the dominoes With Rules :

- **NO** two connected tiles have a number in common.
- 2 dominoes have been placed there as guide.
- There are 2 different solutions, find them all.

[image]

**Solve This.**

[image]

Comment: Oh hey, it's the Petersen graph! (Also, if you were going to place some tiles already, why not do it enough to force a unique solution, so we could actually *deduce* it through *logic*?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clockwise round the outside

> 12,04,23,01,24,03

for the inner three

> 12,34,14

and the centre

> 02

Then

> the mirror-image is another solution. :  12,03,24,01,23,04 : 14,34,12 :  02

Comment: can you provide the second solution?

Comment: numbers listed, explaination same.